# Finding an approximate solution to a differential equation using finite difference method.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a differential equation $$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=-2$$ on the square $$0 \leq x,y \leq 1$$ subject to the boundary conditions $u=0$ along $x=0$ ,$y=0$ and $x=1$.

And $u=1$ along $y=1$

The finite difference approximation to the differential equation at grid point $(i,j)$ is expressed as $$u_{i+1,j}+u_{i-1,j}+u_{i,j+1}+u_{i,j-1}-4u_{i,j}=2h^2$$

I am trying to obtain the finite difference equations for 4 elements or subintervals in both the x and y directions.

For the boundary condition along $x=0$, why do $u_{1,1}=0$, $u_{1,2}=0$, $u_{1,3}=0$, $u_{1,4}=0$? How are they derived?

Surely they should be $u_{0,1}$,$u_{0,2}$ etc...?

Comment: It depends on how you define your indices. With $4$ subintervals, you can let $i$ be $0,1,2,3,4$, or you can let $i$ be $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$. If you start from $0$, then of course $u_{0,0}, u_{0,1},...$. If you start from $1$, then $u_{1,1}, u_{1,2},...$.

Comment: What would it be for $x=1$ and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following picture. You can do it similarly with $i=0,1,...$

[image]

Comment: I think I understand now, so is the square $0 \leq x,y \leq 1$ a square with axis going from 0 to 4 in step size 1/4?

Comment: @Aljabra: Should go from $0$ to $1$ with step size $1/4$.

Answer (score 1):

You said yourself that $u(x,y) = 0$ along $x=0$, it just seems that the text you are using started to number indices from $1$, not from $0$...

Comment: Why is boundary condition along $x=1$, $u_{5,2}=0$,$u_{5,3}=0$,$u_{5,4}=0$?

Comment: @Aljabra because $u(1,y) = 0$